# AngularFire: Saves Once, Stops Saving

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm using [AngularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md) in my Ionic/Angular web app.

I'm using the `$firebaseObject.$bindTo()` method to bind to one of my objects and setup 3-way binding.

Whenever I modify the `$firebaseObject` the FIRST time, that change is synced to the Firebase database. However, any subsequent modifications to *any* of the properties in my `$firebaseObject` will not be updated in the Firebase database. The view will still update correctly, but nothing is pushed to Firebase.

I've tried calling `$save()` manually, but it doesn't do anything.
I tried unbinding and rebinding after each change, and that doesn't do anything either.

The code isn't really setup to show a simple example here, but does anyone have any debugging tips or clues as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use it in a wrong way.
I have just tested this code and 3-way binding works fine.

```
var obj = $firebaseObject(rootRef.child('pathToChildRef'));
obj.$bindTo($scope, 'myVariable');
```

Checkout the following link for more info.

https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#bindtoscope-varname